# Navigating from Webview to an app page in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I'm having my website cloned into an application completely. However for maps purposes, im trying to navigate to my application page which is not a webview.
can someone please guide me through this? Below is my code.

```
    private void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView view = new WebView();
        view.Reload();
        if (e.Url.Contains("thank-you-woo"))
        {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            DisplayAlert("Track", "Tracking Started", "Close this alert");
           NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

    }
```

Please note, pushasync or navigation page, both of the are not taking me to the desired page.

Comment: is the webview page already contained within a NavigationPage?

Comment: You are creating a new navigationPage but you are not replacing the actual one. You might have to do something like `Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())`

Comment: Its not clear from the code you show, what you are doing. You create a WebView - but don't put it anywhere to be visible in the UI. You create a new NavigationPage - why? What do you have on screen, at the time this code runs - show the code that created that. How does WebView_Navigated get called in the first place? You are showing some WebView? AND then want to do what? Need a more detailed description of what is supposed to be happening, and then all relevant code. E.g. "First I show (whatever was visible at first), via this code". Then I'm trying to show (what you want to be visible now)..

Answer (score 0):

Set the NavigationPage in App.xaml.cs and then use the Navigation.PushAsync works for me.

App.xaml.cs:

```
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page29());
    }
```

Page29.xaml.cs:

```
  async void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page30());
    }
```